# syslogd does not understand console.* rule in syslog.conf with error " syslogd: unknown facility name "console"

Tags: linux, logging, console, syslog, rsyslog

I am trying to redirect all the messages/logs that are displayed on the console to be redirected to /ver/log/console.log. I tried to do this using syslogd with a rule added in syslog.conf but it is not working.

My syslog.conf file is below,

```
kern.*                  /var/log/kernel.log
**console.*               /var/log/console.log**
auth,authpriv.*         /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none  /var/log/messages
user.*                  /var/log/user.log
```

when I start the syslog I see below error.

## syslogd

```
 **syslogd: unknown facility name "console"**
```

Any idea on how to fix this or any alternative to capture the console logs in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred while using the busybox version of syslogd(&klogd). Once I enabled both klogd and syslogd from build-root it was able to record all the logs successfully. 
Also using rsyslogd is more convenient way.